# Is there a way to get the subscriptions at a consumer PULL, NOT the producer PUSH for SQL Server replication detail?

Tags: .net, sql-server, t-sql, replication

Is it possible to gather pull subscription data for pull subscriptions the same as push subscriptions?  My problem is I can go to each and every server that is doing the pushes individually but I have a setup were there are many pushes into a single database and server.

I see there is the proc 'sys.sp_replmonitorhelpsubscription' but reading up on MS I did not see anything to swithc it to get pull data.  Which is strange as the return 'subtype' column can indicate it.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188073.aspx

I have read up a little on this page as well: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms147874.aspx.  However after trying many of the calls I either missed something or need to potentially go the .NET route and would not mind having a C# or VB.Net routine either to get the data.  My end purpose is basically interrogating a replicated database that has many inputs in, has a change table capture on a table or two, ensure they are not having records in transit, push an SSIS task to get data from the replication OLTP into a more OLAP structure of a Data Warehouse.

Picture for clarification of want:
[image]

Comment: To confirm, you have a centralized subscriber model, and you are looking to get the subscription information from the distributor or subscriber?  See if table distribution.MSsubscriptions has what you want.

Comment: Yes, it is centralized subscriber getting data from push publications from multiple distributors.  No, I tried that table and it appears to only have data from the local publications subscriptions.